# Javascript Regex: extracting variables from paths

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to extract variable names from paths (variable is preceded with : ,optionally enclosed by ()), the number of variables may vary

"foo/bar/:firstVar/:(secondVar)foo2/:thirdVar"

Expected output should be:

['firstVar', 'secondVar', 'thirdVar']

Tried something like

`"foo/bar/:firstVar/:(secondVar)foo2/:thirdVar".match(/\:([^/:]\w+)/g)`

but it doesnt work (somehow it captures colons & doesnt have optional enclosures), if there is some regex mage around, please help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture here? Can you tell us what results you expect?

Comment: these are strings, so dont quite get what do you mean by newlines

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Why would you want to do this? Why does the URL look so mangled? Why aren't you extracting variables from a query segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var path = "foo/bar/:firstVar/:(secondVar)foo2/:thirdVar";

var matches = [];
path.replace(/:\(?(\w+)\)?/g, function(a, b){
  matches.push(b)
});

matches; // ["firstVar", "secondVar", "thirdVar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
/\:\(?([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\)?/
```

matches:

```
:firstVar
:(secondVar)
:thirdVar
```

`$1` contains:

```
firstVar
secondVar
thirdVar
```

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend that you look into the [URI template specification](http://bitworking.org/projects/URI-Templates/)?  It does exactly what you're trying to do, but more elegantly.  I don't know of any current URI template parsers for JavaScript, since it's usually a server-side operation, but a minimal implementation would be trivial to write.

Essentially, instead of:

```
foo/bar/:firstVar/:(secondVar)foo2/:thirdVar
```

You use:

```
foo/bar/{firstVar}/{secondVar}foo2/{thirdVar}
```

Hopefully, it's pretty obvious why this format works better in the case of `secondVar`.  Plus it has the added advantage of being a specification, albeit currently still a draft.

Comment: Thanks for info, but binded by format (its Horde_Routes syntax)

Comment: Ah, yes.  Another project infected by Rails-esque routing.  Oh well, worth a shot.