# Change image source after page load for select links

Tags: javascript, image

I'm looking to change two image sources that are being generated by an app after page load. What is currently occurring is the app is loading 4 images from the local website's collections, all of which are thumb sized versions. I'm trying to change these links that are being generated after page load for the last 2 images to load normal sized images. The file structure it uses is `..../small/img` and I need to change it to `..../large/img`. I'm not finding a lot of information on how to do this for image sources, so I turn to SO. Thanks!

**ADDITIONAL**

I have found what looks to be what is in the right direction to a solution, but still misses the mark by a lot. Hopefully this can help someone give me a solid answer.

```
  function changeImage(img) {
    document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace("small", "large");
  }
```

I may be completely incorrect, but if this kind of does it then the last step is just figuring out how to target just the last two images without any unique id, similar i guess to the css selector `:nth-child(3)` & `:nth-child(4)`. I've added the javascript tag, though i'm open to (if it's even possible) any non-javascript solutions.

**EDIT**

I was able to change the class for the bottom section which makes up the last two images, the html reflects:

```
   <div class="parent1">
     <a>
      <img />
     </a>
   </div> 
   <div class="parent1">
     <a>
      <img />
     </a>
   </div> 
   <div class="parent2">
    <a>
     <img />
    </a>
   </div> 
   <div class="parent2">
    <a>
     <img />
    </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Since you cannot modify the markup -- To get your nested img elements [document.querySelectorAll(".class > a > img")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You can adjust the selector string as needed.

Comment: Also, your replacement algorithm may clobber the filename portion of the path i.e. `/large/imglarge001.jpg`. You may want to use a regex with capture groups instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780364/javascript-regex-extracting-variables-from-paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dThe problem with the javascript code you have provided is that you have used the `getElementById()` function in order to pick up each of your images. In order to have valid HTML, the ID must not occur more than once on any web page.

Instead, you could use a class and select them with: `document.getElementsByClassName('myImages')`

```
<img class="myImages" src="..."/>
<img class="myImages" src="..."/>
<img class="myImages" src="..."/>
<img class="myImages" src="..."/>
```

or you could select them by their tag name: `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` with this option, you need to be careful that there are no other images on your webpage.

As for changing the source, the code you have provided is pretty much there, the only thing missing is that you would need to loop through each of the elements in turn.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('randomClass');

var images = parent[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 2; i < images.length; i++) {
    var src = images[i].src;
    images[i].src = src.replace("small", "large");
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tz7mav3c/2/) to demonstrate, you will need to right click and inspect the elements to see the changed src once the page has loaded.

**Edit**

Given the additional HTML markup, the following javaScript code should provide the desired results ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tz7mav3c/4/)):

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent2');

for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    var image = parent[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
    var src = image[0].src;
    image[0].src = src.replace("small", "large");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm not sure if it's possible (the code i copied was from a similar question), but what i really need to target is images being generated by the app, that are inside a container, so like .class > a > img. The biggest challenge is figuring out how to target the last 2 of these images only (as there are 4 that exist).

Comment: @NathanKTC I have edited my answer to show how you can target the last two

Comment: Also, as this is being generated by an app, i have 0 control over whether there is an id, class, etc for the images unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for this update, that appears to be pretty close to what I'm aiming for, would you know how i could target it by parent's class, such as `document.getElementByClassName('class > a > img')` as the parent to the link to around the images is the only item with a unique identifier.

Comment: @NathanKTC instead of .getElementByClassName() use [document.querySelectorAll(".class > a > img")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: @NathanKTC yes, but you cannot select the same way as you would select with CSS if you are using pure javascript. I've made a further update to the code; I've assumed here that there will only be one element with the parent class name, and your images will be contained within the first.

Comment: @Ben thank you, i think one more edit and we might have it, I was able, in the settings, to change the class for the section that makes up the last two images. So the current structure is *EDIT* Reflected in my question. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @ben thank you, it's not working for me, is it possible it's loading before the app populates the content?

Comment: @Nathan It will depend on how the content is loaded and where you have placed the javascript code.

Comment: I got it working with `window.onload = function()` 
Thank you for all your help, i know this turned into quite a challenge so i appreciate you sticking with me on this!